# Ultisnips py3 errors

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python, plugin-ultisnips

I have these following errors whenever I try to get into insert mode (see images). I am confused about how to resolve them. I did try uninstalling and reinstalling [SirVer/ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), but didn't change anything.

[image: none]

Error message text:

`Error detected while processing /home/mahbub/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line 7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim`

[image]

Error message text:

`Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange:
line 1:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 UltiSninps_Manager._track_change()`

Comment: No, it doesn't have python support. I did try to add python support, but 2-3  techniques online didn't work, I am not sure how to add that either. I am using Linux (mint cinnamon), vim version is 8.2, the latest one, and I installed vim myself.

Comment: In trying to add python support, I thought let me just uninstall vim and the reinstall. So I had uninstalled vim including `vim-tiny` and reinstalled it. Do you think something wrong might have happened there? Kind of confused about how to fix it.

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: I tried all of them, vim-gtk, vim-nox, vim-gnome. Still the same error message.

Comment: I installed `vim-gtk3` as well, still not working.

Comment: `vim --version` says `-python`, `-python3`. `which vim` says `/usr/local/bin/vim`. This is a weird problem, no matter how many times I uninstall vim (by `sudo`) and reinstall, this problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is happening because your Vim doesn't include support for Python, which is required by UltiSnips, as that plug-in is implemented in Python for the most part.

My recommendation is that you should get a Vim binary from your distribution. You mentioned using Linux Mint, so make sure you are not using a `vim-tiny` package, since that package is typically built with most features disabled. Instead, try `vim-gtk`, `vim-gnome` or `vim-nox` which should be more featureful versions of Vim.

You also mentioned in the comments that `which vim` points to `/usr/local/bin/vim`, please note that this path is most likely *not* the one for a Vim installed by your distribution. Instead, your distribution's Vim will be in `/usr/bin/vim` or `/bin/vim` (in modern distributions, these two last paths are typically the same, as `/bin` is usually a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`.)

Not sure how you got a Vim under `/usr/local/bin/vim`, did you happen to install Vim from source over there? Did you get a binary package from somewhere other than your distribution and unpacked it there? In any case, you might want to uninstall that one, to see if things start working back again.

If there's nothing other than Vim installed under `/usr/local` (you can maybe find that with a `find /usr/local` command to list all the files and subdirectories in there), you might be able to just remove that whole tree and recreate just the directories from scratch.

Another option is to change your `$PATH` variable to list `/usr/bin` ahead of `/usr/local/bin`, for example `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` should do that for you. But that is just a workaround. The best option is to uninstall a Vim under `/usr/local` that is clearly not working for you, and make sure the one you install from your Linux distribution is a fully featured and not a minimal build.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108514/discussion-on-answer-by-filbranden-ultisnips-py3-errors).

Answer (score 2):

This might be the problem with vim version.

I reinstalled the vim using `brew`, and alias it.

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim
```

Then, added following in my `~/.zshrc` (for bash users `~/.bashrc`)

```
alias vim=$(find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/vim -name vim -type f | sort -Vr | head -n 1)
```

Now source file (`source ~/.zshrc`) and it should work.
(`source ~/.bashrc` for bash users).

Comment: You shouldn't need the alias, which would also break any time you update, as long as `/usr/local/bin` is higher on PATH then `/usr/bin`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have updated the alias which should stand through the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, tried changing location of vim to home directory. Then Solved

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would benefit from an [edit] that explains the solution and how it works further. For example, it is not clear what "changing location of vim to home directory" means.